# Can I make a draggable element's overflow appear on the opposite edge of its container when dragged off?

Tags: jquery, overflow, draggable

I have an element that is draggable (using jquery) that is currently contained inside a containing div.  I would like to make it so that when it is dragged outside of its container, the overflow appears on the opposite frame edge and although split up, 100% of the object is still displayed in the container.  I have included a diagram to more specifically address my question.  Please let me know if you know of any solution to this.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you make a second copy of the element and drag them both inside a container, so that the left one starts to appear as the right one moves off-screen.

Comment: That would only work once.  I'm looking for it to keep going as many times as the user drags it off.  Further, ultimately I'm looking to put a video in the box.

Comment: Ok, once element A moves off the right of the screen, move it back to the left side. I've written a looping slideshow using this technique and it works well.